# Access Report vs Query Sort Order

Tags: ms-access

I have a query with custom Sorting.

If I Create a report, with no sorting (from the beginning), the query sorting is reflected correct in the report.

Now I have created a report, intially enabling some sorting in the report wizard. Now i can't get that report to reflect the query custom sorting, even if i remove all sorting.

Is the some way to remove the "wizard-set" sorting in a report ?

Comment: Actually the Custom sorting only works in the report, untill i change something in the report layout. After that the sorting is never working.     In my query i have this sorting {ORDER BY (IIf(UUT_Latest_Result_PCB.UUT_STATUS="Error",0,IIf(UUT_Latest_Result_PCB.UUT_STATUS="Terminated",1,IIf(UUT_Latest_Result_PCB.UUT_STATUS="Failed",2,IIf(UUT_Latest_Result_PCB.UUT_STATUS="Passed",3,4)))));}            How do I make the same thing in a report expression ?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, *any* sorting in the source query should be avoided as it will be ignored by the report and even may slow it down.

So, remove sorting from the query, assign your longwinded expression to a field in the source query, and - in the report - apply sorting on that field.